# 『ビンゴカード作成問題』で書いたソースの改善方法について

Tags: haskell

漠然とした質問で申しわけないのですが
お力を貸していただけるとうれしいです

『Ruby初心者必見！？「ビンゴカード作成問題」のリファクタリング風景をお見せします #codeiq』
http://blog.jnito.com/entry/2015/03/06/090106
にあった『ビンゴカード作成問題』をHaskellで挑戦してみました

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
■ルール■
①各列の値は以下の条件を満たすこと
　B：1～15のどれか
　I：16～30のどれか
　N：31～45のどれか
　G：46～60のどれか
　O：61～75のどれか
②毎回異なるカードを生成すること
③どの数値も重複しないこと
④各列はパイプ（|）で区切ること
⑤数字や"BINGO"の文字は右寄せで出力すること
⑥真ん中（FREEになる場所）はスペースを出力すること
＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

```
{-# OPTOINS -Wall -Werror #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, ViewPatterns #-}

import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified System.Random as R

type RangeUnit = (Int, Int)

header = "BINGO"
bingoSize = T.length header
numrange = 15
rangeUnit = take bingoSize $ zip [1,numrange+1..] [numrange, numrange*2..]

body = do
    nums <- mapM (createRondomRange bingoSize) rangeUnit
    return $ formatCell 2 2 nums

viewBingo = do
    b <- body
    return $ map formatline $ map appendSeparatedWord $ headerList : b
    where
        headerList = map (\x -> justifyRightSpace $ T.pack [x]) $ T.unpack header
        appendSeparatedWord = L.intersperse $ T.pack " | "
        formatline = foldl T.append T.empty

createRondomRange :: Int -> RangeUnit -> IO [Int]
createRondomRange range (start, end) = do
    gen <- R.newStdGen
    return $ take range . L.nub $ R.randomRs (start, end) gen

formatCell :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]] -> [[T.Text]]
formatCell rowIndex colIndex vals = 
    L.transpose $ mmap (justifyRightSpace . centerReplaced) vals
    where
        centerReplaced x = if centerVal == x then " " else T.pack $ show x
        centerVal = vals !! rowIndex !! colIndex

justifyRightSpace = T.justifyRight 2 ' ' 

mmap f = map (map f)

main = do
    b <- viewBingo
    mapM_ print b
```

■質問内容
・Haskellらしく書くにはこうしたほうがいい
・この便利関数を使えばこんな回りくどいことしなくていい
・そもそも書く上での考え方が悪(ry

などなど、ソースを改善するお力を貸していただきたいです

また①の数値の範囲について
import qualified Data.List.Split as S
ranges = S.splitEvery 15 [1..75]
で作成したrangesの格リストの値をシャッフルすることで
作りたかったのですが方法がわかりませんでした。
リストの要素をランダムに入れ替える関数はあるのでしょうか

Answer (score 5):

リストの要素をランダムに入れ替えるには、[random-shuffleパッケージ](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle)を使うと楽です。

ビンゴそのものを作成する過程と、それを表示する過程が混じってしまっているために、全体的に読みづらく感じます。特に、各セルをフォーマットするときに、毎回真ん中かどうかをチェックしている辺りなどです。

若干手を抜いているところがありますが、以下のような感じではどうでしょうか。

ビンゴ自体は`[[Maybe Int]]`で表し、`bingo`関数で新しいビンゴを生成します。真ん中の部分は値がないということで`Nothing`を置きます。インデックスでリストの要素を置き換える部分は、[lensパッケージ](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)を使っています。

作成したビンゴは、`showBingo`関数で文字列に変換します。

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Lens ((.~), (&), ix)
import Control.Monad.Random.Class (MonadRandom)
import Data.List (intercalate, transpose)
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
import System.Random.Shuffle (shuffleM)

type Bingo = [[Maybe Int]]

bingo :: MonadRandom m => m Bingo
bingo = replaceCenter <$> mapM (fmap (map Just . take 5) . shuffleM) (chunksOf 15 [1 .. 75])
  where
    replaceCenter l = l & ix 2 . ix 2 .~ Nothing

showBingo :: Bingo -> String
showBingo bingo = unlines $ " B |  I |  N |  G |  O" : map showRow (transpose bingo)
  where
    showRow = intercalate " | " . map showCell
    showCell (Just n) | n < 10 = ' ' : show n
                      | otherwise = show n
    showCell Nothing = "  "

main = bingo >>= putStr . showBingo
```

GHC-7.10.1でチェックしてありますが、それ以前のバージョンではいくつか`import`を追加する必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます

こんなに短く書けるんですね
ただ私のHaskellのレベルが低くてどうなっているのか理解が。。。

写経しながら勉強させていただきます。
ありがとうございました